# when PythonOperator fail how to get this expect

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I know there is an on failed callback that can be implemented directly through context ['task_instance ']. task when there are failed tasks_ ID,Context ['exception '] to obtain the corresponding failed task ID and the status of the failed task. Currently, due to business issues, I cannot use on failed callback, but my approach is to implement a failure alarm regardless of whether it is triggered_ Rule='one_ Failed 'can still understand how on failed callback obtains the task ID and exception, and then obtains this information to make my alarm

Therefore, my question is how to obtain the ID of the failed task and the reason for the failed task